# "complicated" MySQL relational db query

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I don't have lots of experience with relational databases and I'm struggling with this problem for a while but with little luck...

So, I have few tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `shows` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `show_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `playlists` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `items_playlists` (
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `playlist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`playlist_id`),
  KEY `fk01` (`item_id`),
  KEY `fk02` (`playlist_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `subtitles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `line1` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `line2` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `line3` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `items_subtitles` (
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subtitle_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`subtitle_id`),
  KEY `fk01` (`item_id`),
  KEY `fk02` (`subtitle_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `subtitles_txt` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subtitle_text` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY `id` (`id`)
);
```

`playlists.name` is actually reference to `shows.id` value.

`subtitles.line1`, `subtitles.line2` and `subtitles.line3` are each corresponding to `subtitles_txt.id`.

What I need is to get all rows from all tables based on `subtitles_txt.subtitle_text` value with condition that value has a wildcard on the right side (`...WHERE subtitle_text LIKE 'value%'`).

I think that unfortunately I cannot change table structures because this is part of some huge project and lots of other things depend on some of these tables, so I should really make some query out of this...

Comment: " to get all rows"... all what rows? just those in subtitles.text or all data from all tables related to the subtitle text? including shows, playlists etc...?

Comment: I need all data... Including shows, playlists, etc... =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, somehow I managed to retrieve data I need, but I'm not sure if this is a good way, so please do correct me if I made some trivial errors here or if query can be somehow 'simplified'. Thanks :)

```
SELECT st.line1, st.line2, st.line3, ii.title, pp.name, pp.time, ss.show_name, stxt.subtitle_text, stxt2.subtitle_text, stxt3.subtitle_text 

FROM subtitles st

LEFT JOIN items_subtitles iss ON iss.subtitle_id = st.id
LEFT JOIN items ii ON iss.item_id = ii.id
LEFT JOIN items_playlists ipp ON ipp.item_id = ii.id
LEFT JOIN playlists pp ON ipp.playlist_id = pp.id
LEFT JOIN shows ss ON pp.name = ss.id
LEFT JOIN subtitles_txt stxt ON st.line1 = stxt.id
LEFT JOIN subtitles_txt stxt2 ON st.line2 = stxt2.id
LEFT JOIN subtitles_txt stxt3 ON st.line3 = stxt3.id

WHERE st.line1 = ANY (SELECT id FROM subtitles_txt WHERE subtitle_text LIKE 'some_query%')
OR st.line2 = ANY (SELECT id FROM subtitles_txt WHERE subtitle_text LIKE 'some_query%')
OR st.line3 = ANY (SELECT id FROM subtitles_txt WHERE subtitle_text LIKE 'some_query%')
```